# background non material element in html css

Tags: html, css

To be honest, I don't know how to name my issue, but anyway here is what it is 
I want to make a `shape` on background "non-material" so it would be shown as a background item and scroll bar wouldn't show if it is element is going out of the screen
[image]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <section class="header-section">
            <div class="navigation">
                <img class="logo" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ksardas21/ASL_Page/340a62af7672f102cc9d90609777754fbeb458dd/images/logo.svg" alt="logo" height="60px">
                <nav class="nav-bar">
                    <a>
                        Преимущества
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        Сравнение
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        Виды пленки
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        Инструкция
                    </a>
                </nav>
                </div><div class="shape"></div>
            <div class="phone">
                <div class="number">
                    <img src="images/phone.svg" alt="phone" width="10px"></div>
                    <a>8 965-765-64-65</a>
                </div>
                <a class="order">Заказать звонок</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="main-section">

        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <section class="footer-section">
            
        </section>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    :root {
    --footer: #204B67;
    --colorPrimary:#59BBF2;
    --colorPrimaryLighter: #E7F7FF;
    --colorSecondary: #FFD155;
    --font: #000000;
}
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: white;
    transition: ease-out 250ms;
    font-family: Gotham pro;
}
.shape{
    background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ksardas21/ASL_Page/bf9bf4429d1b25f7095a52582d3b605e4bb449c8/images/shape.svg);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 1080px;
    z-index: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
header, .navigation, .nav-bar, .phone{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 1;
}
header{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height: 160px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header-section{
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 1160px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navigation{
    min-width: 450px;
    max-width: 565px;
}
.nav-bar{
    max-width: 450px;
    min-width: 350px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.phone{
    max-width: 325px;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:white;
}
.number img{
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.order{
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    background: var(--colorSecondary);
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 56px;
}
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmb68kyc/)

Comment: add your picture as `background-image` property of a `div` or `body`

Comment: this shape is another `img` element in html file, and still idk how to make this shape "non-material"

Comment: do you know the `src` of that `img` tag? So, if you know then add it as `background-image: url("<IMAGE URL>");` in **css**

Comment: Still, the scrollbar is showing when the `background-image` of element is going outside the screen

Comment: It's not possible for `background image` property. this property never affects the size of element. there is something wrong with your code... consider add all your code to your question please

Comment: Here it is, I added whole code here and reuploaded it on JSFiddle

Comment: make the div 100% of screen then adjust the image position with css `background-position` property. **also remove margins from the div**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232514/discussion-between-ksardas21-and-mmd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are setting background image by css and adjusting it by forcing with margin and padding, header of site with fixed width and shape need 100% width to be set so put the shape div outside of header-section div and set image position with background-position, check the code under given observe the changes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <section class="header-section">
            <div class="navigation">
                <img class="logo" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ksardas21/ASL_Page/340a62af7672f102cc9d90609777754fbeb458dd/images/logo.svg" alt="logo" height="60px">
                <nav class="nav-bar">
                    <a>
                        Преимущества
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        Сравнение
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        Виды пленки
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        Инструкция
                    </a>
                </nav>
                </div>
            <div class="phone">
                <div class="number">
                    <img src="images/phone.svg" alt="phone" width="10px"></div>
                    <a>8 965-765-64-65</a>
                </div>
                <a class="order">Заказать звонок</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="shape">
                    This is shape background
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="main-section">

        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <section class="footer-section">
            
        </section>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and css with this one

```css
:root {
    --footer: #204B67;
    --colorPrimary:#59BBF2;
    --colorPrimaryLighter: #E7F7FF;
    --colorSecondary: #FFD155;
    --font: #000000;
        }
        html{
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }
        body{
            height: 100%;
            background: white;
            font-weight: 700;
            background: white;
            transition: ease-out 250ms;
            font-family: Gotham pro;
        }
        .shape{
            background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ksardas21/ASL_Page/bf9bf4429d1b25f7095a52582d3b605e4bb449c8/images/shape.svg);
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 400px;
            /*margin-left: 500px;*/
            width: 100%;
            height: 1080px;
            z-index: -10;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 24cm -5cm;
        }
        header, .navigation, .nav-bar, .phone{
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        header{
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            height: 160px;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .header-section{
            margin: auto;
            width: 1160px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .navigation{
            min-width: 450px;
            max-width: 565px;
        }
        .nav-bar{
            max-width: 450px;
            min-width: 350px;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
        .phone{
            max-width: 325px;
            min-width: 300px;
            font-size: 12px;
            color:white;
        }
        .number img{
            margin-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
        .order{
            line-height: 40px;
            width: 150px;
            background: var(--colorSecondary);
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 56px;
        }
```

Comment: changed values little bit and worked, thanks!